# Can physical address of memory acquired from hugepage memory be used for DMA?

Tags: dpdk

I am confused when i read the code of dpdk.

Here is my conclusion about DMA:

After invoking pci_set_dma_mask() and pci_set_consistent_dma_mask() to gurantee that the PCI_NIC can address specified bit length, the phy_address of hugepage memory can be straightforward used for DMA.

Is that right? Do i make some mistake someplace? DMA can only be used on low level memory, that is described in LDD3. How could i gurantee that all my hugepage memory is low level memory？

Could you please give me some advice?thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> phy_address of hugepage memory can be straightforward used for DMA. Is that right?

That is the main purpose of physical addresses in each mbuf.

> DMA can only be used on low level memory, that is described in LDD3.

It is system and device dependent in fact.

> How could i gurantee that all my hugepage memory is low level memory?
>   Could you please give me some advice?

DPDK is an open source project, it supports few architectures and there are a bunch of drivers. I suggest you use one of those drivers for a specific platform/architecture as an example and go from there.

Comment: Testbed is a x86_64 architecture server with XL710 ethernet NIC, while the driver is i40e. Maybe my conclusion is right, at least in my test platform. Thanks, it's really helpful.